# Python_Selenium: Need help finding elements

Tags: element

[image: Image 1]

I'm trying to learn selenium.
But on google or on other sites (like some online games), I can't find elements.
On the photo above, I can't locate the 2nd link ("wikipedia the free..") as an element. I have tried everything I found online, like search for different element ech, nothing works.

for examble, on this photo same error, I can't locate them.
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Because the link text is not like that.
When I search and my country's language is Turkish, the link name is given as  `Özgür Ansiklopedi - Vikipedi`. But let's see what selenium says to this situation.
Let's get the link element with xpath.

```
 s1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div[9]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a')
```

Let's see what the text of this is.

```
s1.text

OUTPUT: 'Özgür Ansiklopedi - Vikipedi\ntr.wikipedia.org \u203a wiki \u203a Ana_Sayfa'
```

You have to get the link using a different method. Class name or xpath. Or another method is to pull the whole a element and choose "wikipedia the free .." in it.

Comment: Thank you very much, u helped me unsterstand, how exacly the xpath works. I really own you a lot! thanks again.